# How can I parse specific data points from an excel file?

Tags: python, excel

**Background:** Electrical Engineer with some programming experience

**Problem:**
I have an excel file that follows this format:

| TimeTag | DataItem | label (decimal) | label (Octal) | ParsedData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time1 | Item1 | ### | ### | Data |
| time2 | Item4 | ### | ### | Data |
| time3 | Item2 | ### | ### | Data |
| ...... | ...... | .............. | ............ | ......... |

This file is already parsed from multiple .bin files, but contains far too much info if you are looking for specific data points. I am writing a script that will ask the user for a range of TimeTags and which DataItems they want to parse. My function "parse" will read in the excel file, start & end timetag, and relevant data items. It will output an new excel find containing only the data relevant to the user, My thought process is this:

1. Find column 'TimeTag'
2. Within this column grab all rows that are between the Start and End timetags
3. Within these chosen rows find Item1, Item2, etc. in column 'DataItem'
4. For the Data Item names found in the chosen time range, find their matching values in column "ParsedData"

The end goal is a new excel file that only the data relevant to the user following this format:

| TimeTag | Item1 | Item2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| start | data | data |
| time# | data | data |
| time# | data | data |
| .... | ........... | ............ |
| end | data | data value |

```
# datafile - C:/.../.../Desktop/FileName
# time - list of start & end time format ['hh:mm:ss:ms','hh:mm:ss:ms']
# relevantdata - list of strings ['DataItemName1','DataItemnName2',...]

def parse(datafile,time,relevantdata):
    df = pd.read_excel(datafile,names=['TimeTag','DataItem','ParsedData'])
    #range_of_columns = pd.read_excel(datafile,usecols="B,C,K")
    df_filtered = df[df['TimeTag'].between(time[0],time[1])]
```

This is my parse function. I have an Idea of what I want to do, but I do not know how exactly to implement it or whether or not pandas is the right library.

Comment: https://www.python-excel.org/